# ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR: OnReconnected method

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

In previous SignalR versions there was OnReconnected() method in Hub class. But now there are only OnConnectedAsync()/OnDisconnectedAsync() methods.
How to detect reconnection event in Hub?

Comment: As far as I know, ASP.NET Core SignalR no longer supports automatic reconnect if the transport connection or the server fails. In older versions, in case of server failure the client attempts to re-establish a connection according to a scheduling algorithm and, if successful, it reopens a connection with the same ID. In SignalR Core if the connection drops the client can only start it again via the method start and this results in a different connection instance over a different connection ID. So, it remove the Reconnected method from hub. You could try to use the client onreconnected event.

Comment: Besides, if you want to detect reconnection event in Hub, you could try to create a client method and call it from the hub, then, based on the result to determine whether it is reconnection or not. Reference: [Reconnect clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#reconnect-clients).